# Doing intersection in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am encountering a problem about intersection functionality.

I have the following mapping:

```
{
    "message": {"type": "text"},
    "created_at": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"}
}
```

Now I want to implement a monitor program, finding out the messages that do NOT show up in the past N days (say N=3 or N=7) but show up today with count >= M. For now, I am able to find out the messages that do NOT show up in the past few days independently, and the messages that show up today with count >= M independently, but HOW CAN I PERFORM AN INTERSECTION?

Is there any better solution? Other than finding out two separate set and doing intersection.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your individual conditions using [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)?